# Get value from an html templates and store it in mysql db through django without using form

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need the code for updating data to database(mysql) through html submit button in Python/Django.need view.py contents with html code.consider I am having a table with bookname,authorname & publishername i need to update the values these values through an html submit button.

Plese help me in this..I am new to this framework...not able to get through.

It will be more thankfull if you send me a code for edit a table in mysql througn Django/Python

Kindly provide me a code without using form,i am using html templates not form...plz

Comment: what you have tried ?  atleast post your html form

Comment: This type of problem is addressed in the tutorial, so you really do need to be more specific about what your problem is. What have you tried? What errors are you getting? What output do you expect? What output are you getting? What `html` are you using? What is your template code?

Comment: Don't expect the community to do all the work for you. Post some code and shown [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: my html is<html>
<head>
<title>{{ page_title }}</title>
</head>
<body>   
<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>
<tr>
       <form action="/addbook/" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="output"></input><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
 <p>value: {{book}}</p>
    </form>
    <p> Output: {{ output }} </p>
    <p>{{ book_name }}</p>
</tr>  

  
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user2086641 Post your code in your question. Not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
   book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True)
   author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True)
   publisher_name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True
```

)

view.py

```
def save_book(request):  
 if request.POST:
   book_name       = request.GET.get('book_name')
   author_name   = request.GET.get('author_name')
   publisher_name = request.GET.get('publisher_name') 
   Book.object.creat(book_name, author_name,publisher_name)
```

In html,
pass these value using querystring

Answer (score 2):

If your html form is like this

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1 />
    <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2 />
</form>
```

you can get the values in **views.py** like this:

```
if request.POST:
    field1_value = request.POST['field1']
    field2_value = request.POST['field2']
```